# Getting Spring boots 404 using Ingress: /api/user in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, custom-error-pages

recently I deployed my Spring boot API in local kubernetes(K3D), all works fine until I specify an ingress with path: /api/user. That ingress path localhost:9080/api/user returns Spring boots 404, so not nginx 404. When reducing the path to /user it works.

not working ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: user-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/user
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: user-service
            port:
              number: 8094
```

the yaml above gives the Whitelabel error page from Spring boot. So it does get through but not with the right path for Spring boot?

working ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: user-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /user
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: user-service
            port:
              number: 8094
```

Above works.

Why does it break when adding /api in path?

I have searched for related problems/solutions but found none.

According to docs it should work:https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: Possibly the source of this concern is from the configuration, does the /api/user is configured properly from your deployment? /user path seems configured correctly since it was working properly as you mentioned.

Another reason I can also see is from the error message which is the spring boot. Based on this link[1] handlers may not be properly defined and need to add from your deployment.

[1]https://www.smashplus.com/how_to_resolve_whitelabel_error_page_in_spring_boot_-tut14429#:~:text=Spring%20Boot%20Whitelabel%20Error%20Page%20for%20the%20Error%20Code%20404&text=The%20probable%20chances%20

Comment: @YvanG. Thx for the reply I will try to fix it with this new info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @YvanG. said, there was something wrong with my configuration in Spring Boot. I had to set the request mapping to: `RequestMapping("/api/user")` in my controller. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Hi, just to add on this concern for other users to see. Providing /api/user to your ingress yaml will route your traffic to a different folder that is why from this path we are having a different result from just providing /user.
Mapping /api/user is what we found out that will solve this concern. Also I just want to share that spring boot error message with code of 404 is that the handlers are not properly defined that is why when we use /api/user in path this resource is not found.